# extract several value using Regular Expression in Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract several value using regular expression in python

The string is `id : NAA1, priority : 4, location : WJQ, director : 13, text : HelloWorld`

"NAA1, 4, WJQ, 13, HelloWorld" is the value what I want.

At first time, I tried like that

```
import re
msg = "id : NAA1, priority : 4, location : WJQ, director : 13, text : HelloWorld"
_id = re.search('id : (.*?),', msg)
```

But I want all value using just one re pattern matching.

Comment: You are searching for `id` specifically, but seem to want anywthing after a colon, and don't mind if you have `priority` or whatever before it.

Comment: Do you need regex? You could just split the text on the commas and colons, and trim the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
import re
msg = "id : NAA1, priority : 4, location : WJQ, director : 13, text : HelloWorld"
print(re.findall(r' : ([^,]*)', msg))
```

Output:

```
['NAA1', '4', 'WJQ', '13', 'HelloWorld']
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex finds each of the strings afer ": " until a space is found. For this to work on the entire string a space should be added to the end of it.

```
import re
string = string + ' '
result = re.findall(': (.*?) ', string)
print(' '.join(result))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
STRING_ = "id : NAA1, priority : 4, location : WJQ, director : 13, text : HelloWorld"
re.findall(r':([\s\w\d]+)',STRING_)
>>>[' NAA1', ' 4', ' WJQ', ' 13', ' HelloWorld']
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using regex:

```
a = "id : NAA1, priority : 4, location : WJQ, director : 13, text : HelloWorld"
print [i.split(":")[1].strip() for i in a.split(",")]
```

**Output:**

```
['NAA1', '4', 'WJQ', '13', 'HelloWorld']
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without using regex:

```
msg = "id : NAA1, priority : 4, location : WJQ, director : 13, text : HelloWorld"
extracted_values = [value.split()[-1] for value in msg.split(", ")]
print(", ".join(extracted_values))
```

Output:

> NAA1, 4, WJQ, 13, HelloWorld